# Accessing parent thread's variables from a child thread

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I have created a thread using this code:

ToServer variables is created in Client.cpp, in main function. ToServer varaible has his buffer.

```
CLI ^console = gcnew CLI(ToServer);
Thread ^consoleThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(console, &CLI::Start));
consoleThread->Start();
```

I get error on this method, when trying to format data in buffer bedfore sendding. Error accures on line

> head->tag = htons(Globals::CommandTag);

```
struct header{
 USHORT tag;
 ULONG lenght;
};

const unsigned short int Globals::CommandTag = 0;
```

In CLI I call this method:

```
void ToServerSocket::CommandList(int page){
   this->head = (struct header*) this->buffer[0];
   head->tag = htons(Globals::CommandTag);
   head->lenght = htons(sizeof (listCommand) );
   listCommand* list = (struct listCommand*) this->buffer[sizeof(header)];
   list->command = htons(1);
   list->page = htons(page);
   this->Send(this->buffer, sizeof(head)+sizeof(listCommand));
}
```

How can I access parent variables from this thread?

When I try to change parent's variables in `ToServer` object I get this error:

> Attempt to read or write protected memory

Comment: This is very likely a scoping issue, not a threading issue. You'll need to post the code that defines the variable, as well as the code that attempts to access the variable, in order for us to help you.

Comment: @CodyGray Please, take a look at my code.

Comment: There's not a scrap of C++/CLI code in the snippet.  You are getting the native code wrong, it must be `this->head = (struct header*) &this->buffer[0];`